# and out stamped this Alabama varsity -- what does that mean?

Tags: comprehension

Example:

> *Q*. Why do the Alabama Crimson Tide have an elephant as their mascot?
> *A*. A fan called them elephants during a 1930 game against Ole Miss and the name stuck.
> "At the end of the quarter, the earth started to tremble," sportswriter Everett Strupper wrote in the October 8, 1930, Atlanta Journal. “Some excited fan in the stands bellowed, ‘Hold your horses, the elephants are coming,’ **and out stamped this Alabama varsity**.’’ Sportswriters dubbed the team’s linemen the “Red Elephants.”
>   That 1930 team had a 10-0 record, outscored its opponents 217-13, defeated
>   Washington State in the Rose Bowl, and was declared national champions.

I'm not exactly sure what that means.

Comment: The magician waved his wand over the hat and **out** popped **this** rabbit.  Storytelling style.

Comment: @MarkH - Great answer (hint, hint).

Comment: @MarkHubbard At dictionary.com, the 2nd definition of **stamp** as instrasitive is: _to strike the foot forcibly or noisily downward._ Hint hint hint.

Comment: Um, why is there a proofreading close vote on this?

Comment: In addition to MH's fine answer, I'd add that it is a very fine example of Subject Complement inversion. The Locative Complement of the verb "come" here is the preposition "out". The Subject is "this Alabama varsity", which means the university football team. The Subject and the Complement have swapped places. The normal phrase order is "[This Alabama varsity (team] stamped [out]. "Out" here means 'out onto the pitch'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "At the end of the quarter, the earth started to tremble," sportswriter Everett Strupper wrote in the October 8, 1930, Atlanta Journal. “Some excited fan in the stands bellowed, ‘Hold your horses, the elephants are coming,’ and **out stamped this Alabama varsity.**’’ Sportswriters dubbed the team’s linemen the “Red Elephants.”

The **bolded** phrase means,

> **"Members of the varsity football team of the University of Alabama ran out onto the playing field"**; i.e., as metaphorical "elephants," the team of football players "stamped" onto the field to begin the game.

It's a bit of poetic license on the part of the sports writer. [Stamped](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stamp) here means,

> "to walk with forcible or heavy, resounding steps: e.g.,
>   *He stamped out of the room in anger.*"

(From definition 12 of "stamp" at Dictionary.com)